Что лучше для эмуляции регистров int или uint
Надо мне эмулировать 8/16/32 разрядные регистры для виртуального процессора
Но я запутался и не знаю какой тип данных надо использовать, signed или unsigned (int8/16/32_t или uint8/16/32_t)
И есть ли разница в этом случае, будет это влиять на то как данные будут храниться?

Если коротко - используйте unsigned. Разница есть - signed вам сломает голову внезапно вылезающими отрицательными числами там где старший бит вдруг окажется равным 1.

В C++ переполнение знаковых типов - неопределённое поведение, а беззнаковые гарантировано работают по модулю. Поэтому эмуляцию знаковых команд придётся делать, либо осторожно, либо с настройкой компилятора. Впрочем, к сожалению, правила приведения целых типов C++ непросты и, во вроде бы простых выражениях, беззнаковый тип может быть преобразован к знаковому, так что...

"эмулировать" - стоило бы раскрыть поподробнее, что под этим подразумевалось. В общем случае, для этих целей можно и массив байт использовать.

@user7860670 эмулировать значит эмулировать, тут поподробнее я не могу сказать, но я сказал что хочу создать процессор, и мне нужно создать "виртуальные" регистры, а на счёт массива байта, ну во-первых в с++ нету такого понятия как байт, например как в джава где есть отдельный тип данных "байт", но в с++ есть int8, uint8, вот и не знаю что надо использовать

@insolor Насколько я понимаю нужно использовать беззнаковые, но тогда будет ли программа работать правильно, если в регистре окажется отрицательное число? Так как у меня должна быть поддержка чисел этого типа

"в с++ нету такого понятия как байт" - сильное заявление, учитывая, что байты в С++ являются основой модели памяти "The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte." [intro.memory] и есть соотв. тип std::byte. А чтобы определиться, с тем, что нужно использовать, сначала придется определиться с конкретными операциями, скрывающимися под мутным словом "эмулировать".

Я даже и не знал что std::byte существует), возьмите во внимание что я с++ недавно начал изучать, вот и поэтому так высказался, и не так понял вас

@Nazar с точки зрения процессора нет разницы между знаковыми и беззнаковыми числами. Почитайте про дополнительный код. Например, операция сложения или вычитания одна и та же, независимо от того, что там - беззнаковые числа, или положительные/отрицательные числа в дополнительном коде. Для деления и умножения разница будет, но тут нужно использовать разные операции, а сам процессор не отличит знаковое число от беззнакового.

@Nazar, вам уже много раз сказали -- unsigned (и с этим я согласен). А вот для программирования эмуляции (моделирования) лучше используйте Си (да, не С++, а простой (без крестов) С).

@avp а чем с++ не угодил, что надо С использовать? Я привык к таким штукам как классы, пространства имен, разные библиотеки которых нет в с,..., и сам с++ это расширенный С, там есть почти те же возможности, не понимаю почему он не подходит

@Nazar, C++ слишком сложен, чтобы его правильно и эффективно использовать (недаром Дейкстра как-то сказал -- "... С++ damages the brain..."). Про KISS-принцип слышали? Это как раз про то, как и на чем надо программировать компьютеры. Кстати, для моделирования компьютера никакие библиотеки не нужны. Достаточно одних массивов (внутри компа, в его железе, никаких иных структур данных просто нет)

И еще одно, кстати. Вы не поверите, но все проблемы с UB (с чего вы и начали) пошли именно из реализаций С++ (как тут не вспомнить Дейкстру...)

@avp Кстати, для моделирования компьютера никакие библиотеки не нужны - Мне хоть и немного но нужны,например векторы, не надо волноваться что забуду освободить память, а главная фишка в динамическом размере, хоть и в самом процессоре он не нужен, но в некоторых частях программы он мне нужен, но не знаю есть ли их альтернатива в С или нет, так как я его не изучал

@avp насколько я понял, в С не будет этих проблем, и можно спокойно писать процессор, не волнуясь если что то пойдёт не так?
